# Restate theorem without final sentence

Tags: theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I am short on space for my paper, so I want to put some theorem proof in appendix, but I also want to put the sentence saying "Proof in appendix" on the same line as the theorem statement.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}
\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
{\em (Proof in appendix)}
\end{restatable}

\newpage\appendix

\section{Appendix}
\goldbach*

\begin{proof}
It is trivial.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image: wig]

What I want:

[image: wiw]

What should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I came up with is simply to have a command `\proofinappendix` that I redefine to nothing in the appendix:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}

\newcommand\proofinappendix{\em (Proof in appendix)}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}
\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\proofinappendix
\end{restatable}

\appendix

\renewcommand\proofinappendix{}

\section{Appendix}
\goldbach*

\begin{proof}
It is trivial.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Good idea, but subject to one weakness: If the main text of the theorem nearly fills its last line, `\proofinappendix` could force an extra (blank) line, not wanted in the appendix.  To avoid this, include the space in the definition and omit space before inputting the command.  (I.e., if you put it on a new line in the input, end the previous line with a `%`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm confused. Wouldn't in the appendix that space form discardable horizontal glue at the end of the last line of the paragraph?

Comment: @UlrichDiez -- I didn't actually test this, but I've encountered extra blank lines enough times when the input had an ending space (in the input) on the last visible line and "nothing" (well, nothing printable) following it in the input that I strongly prefer to actively avoid the possibility.

Answer (score 5):

`\IfRestatementTF{<true>}{<false>}` will leave `<true>` when it's used in a restatement, and `<false>` otherwise. Be careful to only use it in `thmtools`-defined theorems, since its implementation is not so robust.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\IfRestateTF{%
  \ifx\label\thmt@gobble@label % or just compared to \@gobble
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Body}
\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\IfRestateTF{This is restatement.}{This is the original statement. \emph{(Proof in appendix)}}
\end{restatable}

%\newpage
\appendix

\section{Appendix}
\goldbach*

\begin{proof}
It is trivial.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Define a command `\proofinappendix`, that you can redefine when `\appendix` starts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}

\newcommand{\proofinappendix}{%
  \unskip\textup{ (Proof in appendix)}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{\renewcommand{\proofinappendix}{\unskip}}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}

\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than $2$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\proofinappendix
\end{restatable}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\goldbach*

\begin{proof}
It is trivial.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As `restatable`-environments shall not be nested you can probably check `\@currenvir`—but this will fail if used within an environment other than `restatable` nested within `restatable`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\restatableenvname{restatable}%
\newcommand\AtIfInRestateableEnvTF{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\restatableenvname
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Body}
\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.%
\AtIfInRestateableEnvTF{ {\em (Proof in appendix)}}%
                       {}%
\end{restatable}

\newpage\appendix

\section{Appendix}
\goldbach*

\begin{proof}
It is trivial.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]